# Getting FATAL: conversion between WIN1252 and UTF8 is not supported when connecting to YSQL from Windows

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying out the Yugabyte Cloud free tier. I tried connecting to the Yugabyte database from pgadmin.

I received the following error on the pgadmin console:

```
C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\runtime>"C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\runtime\psql.exe" "host='acc
1506a-8831-403c-899d-2084f666305e.gcp.ybdb.io' port='5433' dbname='yugabyte' user='admin' sslmode
='prefer' sslcompression='False' " 2>>&1
psql: error: connection to server at "acc1506a-8831-403c-899d-2084f666305e.gcp.ybdb.io" (34.131.1
55.71), port 5433 failed: FATAL:  conversion between WIN1252 and UTF8 is not supported
```

Any pointers on how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your client encoding before running pgadmin. Follow the steps outlined here:

1. open the cmd
2. SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8
3. chcp 65001
4. psql -h your.ip.addr.ess -U postgres